# Is there a way to get notifications sent to a webhook whenever users update/delete their Google Tasks

Tags: google-api

I am trying to find a way to get notifications pushed to a server whenever users update/delete their google tasks.

For Google Calendar events, you can create a watch to get changes to Events resources and notifications pushed to the webhook you specify.

Is there something like this we can use for Google Tasks?